# Unexpected shell interpretation behavior

Tags: shell

I generated some options using shell script, `echo $NLB_EIPS` resulting in `-p "route 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255" -p "route 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255" -p "route 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255"`

I need to append this option to my original command of `docker run <SOME_OTHER_OPTIONS...> -p "route 192.0.0.0 255.255.0.0" -p "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0"`. Thus, my final goal is to run `docker run <SOME_OTHER_OPTIONS...> -p "route 192.0.0.0 255.255.0.0" -p "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0" -p "route 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255" -p "route 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255" -p "route 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255"`

However, using the shell script below results in unintended behavior. Though ${NLB_EIPS[@]} holds `-p "route 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255" -p "route 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255" -p "route 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255"`, log shows me that shell script only interpreted `-p "route` , completely ignoring the part after the whitespace.

```
#!/bin/bash

ADDITIONAL_IPS="1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3"
NLB_EIPS=()
for IP in $ADDITIONAL_IPS; do
  NLB_EIPS+=" -p \"route $IP 255.255.255.255\""
done

echo "Added additional routes to NLB_EIP."
echo "NLB_EIPS: $NLB_EIPS"

docker run <SOME_OTHER_OPTIONS...> -p "route 192.0.0.0 255.255.0.0" -p "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0" ${NLB_EIPS[@]}
```

Any help would be greatful!

Comment: First of all, I don't think you need to double quotes the variables. It should be like this: `NLB_EIPS+=" -p"; NLB_EIPS+=" route $IP 255.255.255.255"`, secondly, you've forgot to quote the array: `docker run <OTHER_OPTIONS> ... "${NLB_EIPS[@]}"`

Comment: Much of what's going on here is covered in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @Darkman, `NLB_EIPS+="..."` doesn't append a new element to an array, it just makes the _first_ array element longer.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Oh really? Well bash is not my strongest subject. I learned something new. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly starting with the idea, that `NLB_EIPS` is an array where each element is a parameter to the command to be executed. But when you do a `NLB_EIPS+=....`, you are populating a single element with a string holding two parameters (`-p`, `route` and the IP address), plus confusing white space surrounding that stuff.

`docker` will never see **that** `-p` which comes in via NLB_EIPS, becaus the parameter is not a sole `-p` anymore. For the same reason,

```
 docker run ' -p "route $IP 255.255.255.255"'
```

would fail.

Comment: They're not even adding a new array element with each `NLB_EIPS+="..."`, they're just making `NLB_EIPS[0]` a longer string. It needs to be `NLB_EIPS+=( ... )` to add new array elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

additional_ips=( 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 )
nlb_eips=()
for ip in "${additional_ips[@]}"; do
  nlb_eips+=( -p "route $ip 255.255.255.255" )
done

echo "Added additional routes to NLB_EIP."
printf '%q ' "${nlb_eips[@]}"; echo

docker run <SOME_OTHER_OPTIONS...> \
  -p "route 192.0.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
  -p "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0" \
  "${nlb_eips[@]}"
```

What's different?

- We're building commands using arrays instead of string concatenation. For an in-depth discussion of how string concatenation is inherently unfit for the purpose, see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).
- We're quoting our array on expansion, ensuring that its boundaries are respected.
- We're using lower-case names for application-defined variables [in accordance with POSIX convention](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).